# Sukka and shemini atzeret havdalah

Tags: sukkah

I am confuse When is succot and shemini atzeret/simkhat torah havdala should be made in diaspora? Should succot havdalah be made at the end of second night?

Comment: Are you asking for an Israeli person in huts laarets or for a resident of diaspora?

Answer (score 1):

*Havdala* is made on the following occasions:

1. At the end of a sabbath. *Havdala* includes a beverage (ideally wine), a flame, and a spice.

   - If the end of the sabbath coincides with a *yom tov* (e.g., the first two days of *Sukos* in the diaspora), then *havdala* with wine and a flame is incorporated into *kidush*, and spices are omitted.
   - [If the end of the sabbath coincides with the fast of the ninth of *Av*, then *havdala* with a beverage is postponed until the end of the fast, and spices are omitted, but the flame is used Saturday night.](/a/18108)
2. At the end of a *yom tov* (e.g., the first two days of *Sukos* in the diaspora. But not after the first day of a two-day *yom tov*). *Havdala* includes a beverage (ideally wine), but excludes a flame (except at the end of *Yom Kipur*) and a spice unless it's also the end of a sabbath.

   - If the end of the *yom tov* coincides with a sabbath, then *havdala* is not said.

Source: experience over many years in the diaspora, primarily in Ashkenazic venues

Comment: Ah sorry I see it now.  Have you an idea if the question is for Israeli or chusnick person?

Comment: @kouty why might you think it's for an Israeli?

Comment: A person who lives in Erets Israel and is occasionally in diaspora

Comment: @kouty, I understand that. I don't understand why you think the question may be that _ukimta_ rather than a simple question about when diaspora people say _havdala_ in the diaspora.

Comment: OK,  the style of the question was perhaps misleading me.  Sorry for an additional remark,  I'm not sure if YK must be called YT